# is there any lib exists for libspotify 12 for android java?

Tags: android, spotify

I want to integrate libspotify as sound/player service and integrate spotify in more then one java applications.

Can anyone suggest me any lib or any code example to get me started?

Answer (score 10):

*Disclaimer: I work for Spotify*

At the moment, Spotify doesn't have a nice Java wrapper for libspotify, but this is definitely something we are thinking about doing in the future. I can't offer an estimate on when this will be available, so if you are dying to get started writing apps which integrate with Spotify, you should use the natively-compiled libspotify for Android rather than waiting for a Java wrapper.

The current preferred way of doing Android work with libspotify is to use the natively-compiled library which can be found on [the libspotify website](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/). You'll have to write your own JNI wrappers around it, which can be a bit tricky, but is definitely not an impossible task. :) Unfortunately the documentation for using libspotify under Android is a bit lacking. Again, this is something that Spotify is working to improve.

There is a third-party project called [jlibspotify](http://code.google.com/p/jlibspotify/) which offers a Java wrapper around libspotify. I personally have not used it before, so I can't comment on how good the project is, but if I recall correctly it is based on an older version of libspotify, so you might be better off going the JNI route detailed above.

Comment: Nick, we're all waiting for you wrapper :P As I already said, if you need help with test&debug I'm always here :)

Comment: Yes, a wrapper would be very helpful :)

Comment: Any updates on the ETA or plans on improving the documentation for libspotify for android?

Comment: @MrMaffen Yes, I'm working on an Android best-practices doc (hopefully will finish that soon when I get the time), and a colleague of mine posted a sample project from his hackdays: https://github.com/spotify/psyonspotify

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is also [libjahspotify](https://github.com/nvdweem/libjahspotify) out there, which seems newer than jlibspotify.  I haven't tried it though.