# Integrating the Spotify Android library

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

So I wanted to integrate the spotify library into an android app. I went to https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/ and downloaded their lib libspotify-12.1.51-Android-arm-release.tar.gz
Problem is that the "Android" samples bundled with the lib aren't actually android projects, they are C code, the lib is a .so file. I have basic knowledge of android ndk and jni but the documentation out there about integrating the library with android is non-existent. Can anyone provide a sample of just playing a track? or point me to where i can find a sample.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115827/how-to-link-libmedia-so-in-android-system-library-from-android-mk/13116716#13116716

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Spotify doesn't have a nice Java library for Android (see this [StackOverflow question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071610/is-there-any-lib-exists-for-libspotify-12-for-android-java)), so you'll have to manually write a JNI wrapper. As the Android build of libspotify is pretty new, there aren't yet any examples for that either, but I wouldn't be surprised to see the documentation include them soon.

As @juned noted in his comment, this question details [how to get the libspotify libraries linked with your Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115827/). Once you get libspotify linked correctly, you can check out [a few Android NDK tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners) for more specific integration help.

If you have troubles during your integration, be sure to check out the example code which Spotify ships with libspotify. The code provides a good reference of how to properly talk with the Spotify service with the library.

Comment: I was able to get started, seems my approach to the whole thing was wrong, i thought i'd just start using the libspotify.so library out of the box but i had to write my own JNI wrapper. Thanks @juned your link helped me in how to include a prebuilt library in this case libspotify.so

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this sample project doing libspotify on Android: https://github.com/spotify/psyonspotify

As documented in the README:

Looking at the code gives you some insight in:

- Integration with libspotify
- Communication through JNI
- Bridging raw PCM data to OpenSL

Answer (score 1):

Spotify have published a SDK BETA version for android.

https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk

They have a few examples of initializing a player and playing a track using TRACK_CHANGE event (Only available from Beta10). 
Here is one that doesn't use TRACK_CHANGE:

```
           mPlayer = Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new Player.InitializationObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onInitialized(Player player) {
                mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(MainActivity.this);
                mPlayer.addPlayerNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
                mPlayer.play("spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

(Took the code from the tutorial - https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Spotify have announced that they released the Android SDK(https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/).
And the tutorial is here(https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/), so you can easily integrate Spotify into your Android application.