# How can I get my Android app to recognize a native method using a library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, native, spotify

I am trying to get Spotify API to work in an Android app.  I currently have access to all the Spotify classes via a Java wrapper, but when if I uncomment the lines:

```
System.loadLibrary("libspotify");
s.Initialise(c);
```

then it says that it cannot find the method NativeCreate().  My project is located at https://github.com/GuacoIV/VisEQ  I used the jar file from this:
https://code.google.com/p/jlibspotify/downloads/list and then also added the libspotify-12.1.51-Android-arm-release from the Spotify developer site.  I am not great with advanced project setup like this and my group is counting on me to figure this out.  I am using Eclipse as my development environment.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What are the variables `s` and `c`?

Comment: I don't think you can mix the jar file from jlibspotify and the libspotify-12.1.51-Android-arm-release from official Spotify this way, since the wrapper and native code would not match. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116815/intergrating-the-spotify-android-library to see if it helps.

Comment: @Phil, s is a Spotify session and c is the configuration setup for that session.

Comment: @TactMayers, thanks, I will check it out.  It looks like I'll have to really read it carefully to understand what it is doing - it looks less straightforward than having a a Spotify class.

Comment: @TactMayers - That example was extremely helpful.  I'd like to mark your comment as the answer to give you credit but am actually not sure how...

Comment: @GuacoIV Glad to know that. You can click the up arrow that appears when you move your mouse to the left of the comment to mark the comment as useful. I think I didn't try hard enough to provide a full answer so an upvote on comment would be grateful enough. Thanks!