# Spotify Library In Android App

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to integrate the Spotify Library into my app. I've look at this:

[Integrating the Spotify Android library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116815/integrating-the-spotify-android-library)

However, the libspotify SDK is soon to be removed. Is there a way to use the Android SDK to integrate the Spotify library? I want to be able to list the different playlists, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively new project for a Spoify Android SDK, see https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/.
It is currently in beta though.